# Using rosbag to get size of each topic

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to remove unnecessary topics from a rosbag file to make it easier to distribute. In doing so, i'd like to know the size of each topic, not just the size of the bag file as a whole. However, running `rosbag info example_bag.bag` only provides me with the size of the bag file and not the size of individual topics.

Is there any way to use the `rosbag` command line tool to obtain the size of individual topics within the bag file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318667/using-rosbag-to-get-size-of-each-topic/) by [Escontrela](https://answers.ros.org/users/29812/escontrela/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-03-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2019-03-19**:
What do you mean by size of topics? You can get the number of messages in the particular topic and data type using rosbag info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue and wrote a python script to solve it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Print total cumulative serialized msg size per topic
import rosbag
import sys
topic_size_dict = {}
for topic, msg, time in rosbag.Bag(sys.argv[1], 'r').read_messages(raw=True):
  topic_size_dict[topic] = topic_size_dict.get(topic, 0) + len(msg[1])
topic_size = list(topic_size_dict.items())
topic_size.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
for topic, size in topic_size:
  print(topic, size)
```

And to explain to simbha why this is useful and needed: I have 102 topics generated by 40+ nodes. Hundreds of thousands of message. I'm not familiar with any of these nodes. But one of them is causing excessive size of bags. As a system administrator/data warehouse guy I want to quickly find out which one exactly so I can contact the responsible developer to fix the issue.

---

Originally posted by [MumboJumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/41659/mumbojumbo/) with karma: 136 on 2019-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raucha](https://answers.ros.org/users/42985/raucha/) on 2019-06-19**:
And if you get "UnicodeEncodeError",
add lines belows

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified **MumboJumbo** code to give human readable output:

To run: `python rosbag_size_by_topic.py BAG_FILE_PATH`  or

`rosrun PACKAGE rosbag_size_by_topic.py BAG_FILE_PATH`

**rosbag_size_by_topic.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Prints total cumulative serialized msg size in bytes per topic
# Calculation takes approximately 1sec/GB
# Usage:   python rosbag_size_by_topic.py BAG_FILE_PATH

import rosbag
import sys

topic_size_dict = {}
for topic, msg, time in rosbag.Bag(sys.argv[1], "r").read_messages(raw=True):
    topic_size_dict[topic] = topic_size_dict.get(topic, 0) + len(msg[1])

topic_size = list(topic_size_dict.items())
topic_size.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)

for topic, size in topic_size:
    if size < 1000:
        print("{:7d}B  {}".format(size, topic))
    elif size >= 1000000000000:
        print("{:7.2f}T  {}".format(size/1000000000000, topic))
    elif size >= 1000000000:
        print("{:7.2f}G  {}".format(size/1000000000, topic))
    elif size >= 1000000:
        print("{:7.2f}M  {}".format(size/1000000, topic))
    elif size >= 1000:
        print("{:7.2f}K  {}".format(size/1000, topic))
```

Example of output:

```
     86B  /tf_static
    775B  /move_base/global_costmap/inflater_layer/parameter_descriptions
    775B  /move_base/local_costmap/inflater_layer/parameter_descriptions
   1.01K  /mobile_base_controller/parameter_descriptions
   1.33K  /move_base/goal
   1.88K  /voxel_grid/parameter_descriptions
 866.76K  /move_base/GlobalPlanner/plan
 921.19K  /path_planner/visualization_marker
   1.10M  /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/local_plan
   1.18M  /imu/mag
   1.19M  /move_base/TebLocalPlannerROS/teb_markers
  19.89M  /tf
 284.01M  /move_base/GlobalPlanner/potential
  19.54G  /move_base/global_costmap/obstacles_layer/voxel_grid
```

---

Originally posted by [Combinacijus](https://answers.ros.org/users/44007/combinacijus/) with karma: 65 on 2022-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1